# Edit and continue with C++? Preferably with Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, debugging, block

I am used to Java and Eclipse, as that was what I first programmed with. That said, in Eclipse, when debugging Java, you can make code changes, and save them, while the code is running. The changes to the code will then take effect in the debug window, without a change to your code.

I am wondering if you can do the same thing, or similar with C++. I am currently using Code::Blocks, and I'm wondering if there is a debugging plugin for it that does the same thing, or similar. I know about Edit and Continue in VS, but I would really rather stick with Code::Blocks. Also, I have not programmed C++ in Eclipse yet, and will hot swapping C++ work in Eclipse? Or is that a Java feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is JIT compiled (just in time, compiled at runtime) making this feature, perhaps not trivial, but not as significant a challenge as it is to implement in a C++ environment. I've been developing in Visual Studio for 10+ years now, and to be honest, I find edit and continue rather useless.

As to having it in Code::Blocks, gcc would have to support incremental compilation before this was put significantly on the agenda of many C::B users. [There was a project to add this functionality](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/IncrementalCompiler), but I'd say at this stage, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways... Its not necessary, just a nice thing from Java that won't be with me after my jump to C++... D:

Comment: @tehB3NJ1E It's an adjustment, my advice to you though is that in C++ you have the compiler, which is a great way to catch a lot of the stuff that you don't catch until runtime in java: just get into the habit of writing good C++, using exceptions, templates and strong typing to your advantage, and you'll be getting results in no time.

Comment: Again, thanks... You have really been a help. The main use for the hot swapping would be changing variables in real-time... mostly for fine-tuning things...(i.e. running spped or jumping height in a game, or text on a screen)

Comment: No problem. I know where you're coming from, especially for tweaking games. In the long run, you'd want to build in some sort of console, a bit fiddley but hey, that's C++ :D.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a feature of the entire *toolchain*, including the compiler, linker, loader, and debugger. Visual C++ has this feature because Microsoft has made all its tools work together to support it. Similarly, the same effort has been spent to make Java work this way.

As far as I know, Code::Blocks is just an *editor* but delegates the compiling and linking to other compilers (without specifically integrating with their features).